# When entering dot(.) calculator crashes

Tags: android

I have the following code for calculating the values entered in 2 of the 3 EditTexts.

```
public void calculeaza() {

    totaltest = 0;
    prod = new String[allprod.size()];
    pret = new String[allpret.size()];
    cant = new String[allcant.size()];

    for (int m = 0; m < allprod.size(); m++) {

        prod[m] = allprod.get(m).getText().toString();
        if (prod[m].matches("")) {
            prod[m] = Float.toString(0);

        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < allcant.size(); j++) {

        cant[j] = allcant.get(j).getText().toString();
        if (cant[j].matches("")) {
            cant[j] = Float.toString(0);

        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < allpret.size(); k++) {
        pret[k] = allpret.get(k).getText().toString();
        if (pret[k].matches("")) {
            pret[k] = Float.toString(0);

        }
    }

    for (int l = 0; l < allpret.size(); l++) {

        Float temp = Float.parseFloat(cant[l]) * Float.parseFloat(pret[l]);

        totaltest = totaltest + temp;

        TextView totalf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
        totalf.setText(String.format("Total: %.2f", totaltest));

    }
}
```

The problem is that it crashes when entering dot(.) first,and not 0.x .How can i prevent this ? or how can i make so that if the user enters .6 for example to automatically make it 0.6 ?
Also is there a way to make both .(dot) and ,(comma) able to be entered for float values ? In my country,we usualy use comma and not dot..

EDIT : Logcat: It fails when calling calculeaza()

```
06-26 00:23:53.952: E/AndroidRuntime(15220): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-26 00:23:53.952: E/AndroidRuntime(15220): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
06-26 00:23:53.952: E/AndroidRuntime(15220):    at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
06-26 00:23:53.952: E/AndroidRuntime(15220):    at java.lang.StringToReal.initialParse(StringToReal.java:163)
06-26 00:23:53.952: E/AndroidRuntime(15220):    at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:304)
06-26 00:23:53.952: E/AndroidRuntime(15220):    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:300)
06-26 00:23:53.952: E/AndroidRuntime(15220):    at com.example.testlayout.MainActivity.calculeaza(MainActivity.java:494)
06-26 00:23:53.952: E/AndroidRuntime(15220):    at com.example.testlayout.MainActivity.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:517)
06-26 00:23:53.952: E/AndroidRuntime(15220):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7231)
06-26 00:23:53.952: E/AndroidRuntime(15220):    at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7290)
06-26 00:23:53.952: E/AndroidRuntime(15220):    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:8880)
06-26 00:23:53.952: E/AndroidRuntime(15220):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:962)
06-26 00:23:53.952: E/AndroidRuntime(15220):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:496)
06-26 00:23:53.952: E/AndroidRuntime(15220):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
06-26 00:23:53.952: E/AndroidRuntime(15220):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
06-26 00:23:53.952: E/AndroidRuntime(15220):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:672)
06-26 00:23:53.952: E/AndroidRuntime(15220):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:196)
06-26 00:23:53.952: E/AndroidRuntime(15220):    at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:183)
06-26 00:23:53.952: E/AndroidRuntime(15220):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:279)
06-26 00:23:53.952: E/AndroidRuntime(15220):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77)
06-26 00:23:53.952: E/AndroidRuntime(15220):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-26 00:23:53.952: E/AndroidRuntime(15220):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-26 00:23:53.952: E/AndroidRuntime(15220):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-26 00:23:53.952: E/AndroidRuntime(15220):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-26 00:23:53.952: E/AndroidRuntime(15220):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-26 00:23:53.952: E/AndroidRuntime(15220):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-26 00:23:53.952: E/AndroidRuntime(15220):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-26 00:23:53.952: E/AndroidRuntime(15220):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace for the crash.

Comment: What is stopping you from making the check in the for loops? `if (pret[k].matches("")) {
            pret[k] = Float.toString(0);

        } else if (pret[k].charAt(0) == '.') {pret[k] = "0" +  allpret.get(k).getText().toString();};`

Comment: Thanks a lot Luksprog,works great ! Didn't knew about .charAt,i learn something new everyday ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) field of `TextView`. I think if you set it to `numberDecimal`, it will always be in the correct format.

Layout:

```
EditText android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
```

Code:

```
EditText ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView);
String s = ed.getText().toString();
float f = Float.valueOf(s);

Log.e(TAG, "Value: " + f);
```

Comment: I have this as the input type : et2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
    | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

Comment: There was no way you could knew but my EditTexts are created dynamically so they aren't in any XML.Thanks anyway,i already fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Use TextWatcher on editText to find "." , convert your string accordingly into decimal fraction and pasre it into double precision point .Do you calculation with final result .